# Determine if a device is running Retina HD?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Checking the screen scale for the iPhone 5s and 6 are the same 2x..

How do you I determine if the device is Retina HD?

Comment: Their answer does not work for iPhone 6...  iPhone 6's scale is being calculated as 2x

Comment: @TimNuwin How does it not work?

Comment: 6 seems to have Retina and 6 Plus Retina HD. So it's normal.

Comment: So you're saying the scale is exactly the same with the iPhone 6 and iPhone 5s?

Comment: Check the ppi: http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/ 326 (iPhone 5 up to 6) vs 401 (iPhone 6+)

Comment: I understand the PPI are the same between those two, but then why do I have to scale the distances at 2X between the 6 and the 5s?

Comment: iPhone 6 does not use a 3x display. 6+ only.

Comment: Just a note on the side: Optimizing UI based on fixed devices / screen sizes is a really bad idea 95% of the time. If you haven't already, try if it is possible to accomplish your goal using Auto Layout and Size Classes (you can access them in code too). You will be better prepared for new devices and functionality (such as side by side multitasking on iPad)

Comment: Yup I realize this, it's legacy code that I am fixing.  It's already using auto-layouts but not fully, I'm working on word-wrapping a UI-Label inside an image.  And it needs to subtract distances for the elements that appear before it..